# Insert number from button to selected place in EditText

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

How can I insert number (from name of button) to specific place in EditText?

Here is an [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCM5r.png)

For selecting I use:

`et.setTextIsSelectable(true);
 et.setFocusable(true);
 et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);`

Now I'm using this code (but it's not useful):

```
Button b = (Button)v; // tapped button
String operations += b.getText();
myEditText.setText(operations);
```

Thank you.

Comment: #1. get string from edittext = edittext.getText().toString()
#2. get current cursor position = getSelectionStart()
#3. substring from 0 till #2. = string1
      substring from #2. till end = string3
      your new text  = string2
#4. set these string in the editText = edittext.setText(string1+string2+string3)

Comment: @DrakeSobania I think the crucial part of his question is how to insert the selected value in the right place (position of cursor in EditText).

Comment: @Ahmad Thank you! But how can I check if selected (focused) specific position in EditText?

Comment: @Ascorbin I think that's right, my fault.

Comment: sorry @VitaliiScrum didn't got u... do u mean to know which editText is focused or meant to get the current cursor position from a edittext ?

Comment: @Ahmad, I mean (if/else conditions), how to know that user has selected position, then do getSelections.. and else if he didn't selected position show wrong toast, sth like that..

Comment: you can use editText.isFocused() when the button is clicked to confirm that this editText is focused and then you will get the current cursor position after which you will follow the steps i wrote before ( according to me :) )

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

```
StringBuffer SB = new StringBuffer();
```

And these helper methods

```
int start = edittextObj.getSelectionStart();
int end = edittextObj.getSelectionEnd();
edittextObj.setSelection();
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I check if selected (focused) specific position in EditText?

Comment: if (start == end) { System.out.println("This is your current cursor position in editext : " + start); } else { System.out.println("Some text is selected in editext start: " + start + ", end:" + end); }